# Extracting all specific value pairs in deeply nested JSON

Tags: python, arrays, json, sorting, dictionary

I have a deeply nested json in the following format:

```
{
"ListId":34,
"FeatCat":[
       {"Id":2,
        "Name":"Arch",
        "FeatGrps":[ 
                    {"Id":3,
                      "Name":"Sty",
                      "Feats":[
                                   {
                                    "Id":32, 
                                    "Name":"Rec"}
                                   ]}]},
       {"Id":9,
        "Name":"F&T",
        "FeatGrps":[ ... ] etc.
```

I'll be comparing two jsons with this format. I want to ensure that these two jsons have the IDs corresponding to the same Name value. The IDs will be unique, so it does not matter if its nested within, FeatGrps, lets say.

To do this, I want to extract **all** the {Id, Name} values. For example: Id = 2 should match with Name = "Arch". Id = 3 should match with "Sty".

How do I get all the [Id, Name] pairs in a format such as: [2, "Arch"], [3, "Sty"]..? It does not have to be this exact list format, anything similar would work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not terribly elegant, but this should do the job:

```py
def id_names(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return sum([id_names(el) for el in obj], [])
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        sub_collections = (val for key, val in obj.items() 
                           if isinstance(val, dict) or isinstance(val, list))
        vals = sum([id_names(it) for it in sub_collections], [])
        if obj.get('Id') and obj.get('Name'):
            vals += [(obj.get('Id'), obj.get('Name'))]
        return vals
```